# A key puncher hates it

Tags: riddle

> - A song mentions it
> - A key puncher hates it
> - It keeps a network together
> - These twines can be paired with wines

What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, take two, I changed my answer.

> <strike>card</strike>
>
>  Spaghetti

A song mentions it

> Plenty of songs speak about spaghetti

A key puncher hates it

> A key puncher is a synonym of a programmer and the programmers hate spaghetti code

It keeps a network together

> The network cables quite often look like spaghetti

These twines can be paired with wines

> The pasta dishes could be paired with different wines.

Comment: Not really, but I like your answer.

Comment: @MateoVD OK, I changed my answer and I think this one fits better your riddle.

Comment: The song was: eminem - lose yourself & The network was more meant as a family. And how everyone loves pasta and it brings/keeps them togethers (bit far fetched)

Comment: @MateoVD I've been punching keys since 1985 and once I got that idea, all the hints looked to me software/hardware related.

Comment: Yup, hope you like it.